# Create milestone in SVN of multiple versions of Components

Tags: svn

I want to create from a development branch a milestone for a build. Some of the components in that milestone are of earlier versions than HEAD.

So in the development branch:

top

```
|- CompA    v: 6
|- CompB    v: 8
|- CompC    v: 10
```

In the milestone tag i want to have:

top

```
|- CompA    v: 5
|- CompB    v: 7
|- CompC    v: 10
```

Tried different ways to do this but I always get the milestone to be the HEAD of the development branch for all components.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know: "Milestone", "Components"... are not words from Subversion, they are from another planets. If you want to be understood, you have to speak the same language, but it is almost impossible with ambiguous terminology.

What is meant by a Component? In Subversion repo it can be:

- plain subdir inside parent dir
- separate independent entity, linked to base using svn:externals

each of the two options involves *different* solution

And side-note: if tag must doesn't correlate to current HEAD, it still, *by convention*, **must** lock state of the repository in a **certain previous revision**, not random set and voluntaristic choice. Just `svn up -r` to *this revision* and tag it